# Some Minecraft sounds are not playing

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have been playing Minecraft Bedrock Edition for some time now on my iPad. I have all sounds enabled in the game settings. However, when I insert a music disc into a jukebox, or use the `/playsound` command to play a valid sound, no sound is elicited from the system.

Here is the list of sounds that are not playing:

- Minecraft ambience
- Music discs
- `/playsound` command

This has continuously happened for over a year now. What is going on, and how do I fix this rather annoying problem?

**Edit:** This problem has nothing to do with hardware issues. Minecraft sound effects, like block breaking, still work fine.

Comment: If I could recall, around the time Pocket Edition got it's 1.0 update (around 2017), they added the in-game music soundtrack as a separate thing that you had to download to your game before the game would start playing background music and music discs. I'm not sure if they eventually included the soundtrack into the game by default once Pocket Edition became Bedrock Edition, or if the mobile device port of Bedrock Edition is still like this. This might possibly be the reason for your issue, but I can't say for 100% that this is the particular issue you're having.

Comment: I think that that's what's going on. Could you please elaborate that in an answer? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to hear music discs on Minecraft Bedrock/Pocket Edition?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/374548/is-it-possible-to-hear-music-discs-on-minecraft-bedrock-pocket-edition)

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that it isn't something involving your device? Because I would assume that after a few years the hardware doesn't work anymore

Comment: No, it's been like that since I got Minecraft PE in 2014.

Comment: oh well in that case im not sure

Comment: 1. Hardware doesn't just pick specific sounds not to play 2. After a few years hardware doesn't break, I have an iPhone 5 that still works fine, its just kinda slow.