# Is it possible to hear music discs on Minecraft Bedrock/Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I have some music discs, but every time I put it in a jukebox I can't hear it. It says it's playing, my friend (on PS4) says he can hear it, but I don't.

All other audio is fine, I can hear the game audio fine, even if I have a world that's only me: it still doesn't produce jukebox sounds. It visually shows that it's playing (the notes come out of the jukebox) but there is no music.

I play on Pocket Edition. Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: This should go without saying, but, make sure the sound is not muted and make sure your system volume is up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Some Minecraft sounds are not playing](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372266/some-minecraft-sounds-are-not-playing)? Also, when did you get Minecraft?

Answer (score 3):

#### How to Fix

You have not installed the free Music DLC from the marketplace. Go to the marketplace and just search up music and there is a free pack by Minecraft.

#### Reason

On pocket edition the music pack doesn't come with Minecraft, rather in a form of free DLC from the marketplace. You must download it from the marketplace. The reason it was not included was because they thought the amount of storage the game took up compared to the music was insane, so they decided to make the music optional as to not waste space some users may not have needed. This isn't as big of an issue now since most newer phones and iPads have a lot of storage, but that is why.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you got Minecraft before 2017, the reason why is because Pocket Edition got its soundtracks and discs in its 1.0 update in 2017. Users who had PE before 2017 had to download a separate "module" for the game for the sounds to load. Even by updating Minecraft PE, you can't hear the ambience or music discs. I got Minecraft PE in 2014, and also have [this problem](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/372266/some-minecraft-sounds-are-not-playing), but I am perfectly fine without having soundtracks. I hope this helps.

Comment: actually I downloded mincraft in early/ mid 2019

Comment: @KrishnaBear Then your hardware is probably wrong.

Comment: I mean my game just kicked me out

Comment: Have you restarted Minecraft?

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the marketplace and scrolling down until you see the music content. You can then download it to your game for free, and should be able to hear background music and discs